# pip.exe install jira is giving Connection to pypi.python. org timed out

Tags: python

On windows 7 on corporate network may be behind firewall not sure. 
Java SE ProxySelector class provided output as DIRECT.

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python. org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/jira/

how to fix this without going to admin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your internet connection,it seems that the Internet is unreachable for you.Or maybe you can choose another [Pypi mirror](https://www.pypi-mirrors.org/).

Also you can specify a proxy as a parameter to pip install:

```
pip install <package> --proxy http://your.proxy.net:8080/
```

And enable pypi as a trusted host if you got ssl certificate errors:

```
pip install <package> --proxy http://your.proxy.net:8080/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Internet is working fine on the machine, I have run Java program to get proxy details but the output is DIRECT. how to fix this?